# Android R.drawable.icon = NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

I have the code below and I keep getting this error in my stack trace "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" the line number points to the .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon) part of the code snippet. The icon exists in the drawable folder and the app works fine on all my test devices. My users are somehow getting this error though. Is there anything you can think of that could cause/fix this?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Click here to use!");
```

Comment: I have the icon inside the drawable-hdpi folder could this issue be caused by lower end devices looking for the icon in drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi or will android know if they don't exist there keep looking in the larger folders for them? 
Edit: just tried it on the simulator using android 2.2 and a screen res of 320x480 and still worked fine so that's not the issue.

Comment: add an icon in the drawable folder

Comment: post complete stacktrace, and more code to give context.

Comment: @Dave I dont think so. Because even we have all the images in hdpi folder, but it still works for mdpi devices too. Do you have your R file imported?

Comment: @Rani You don't need to import your R file.

Comment: Other devices will pick the drawable-xxdpi depending on their dpi.  If the image isn't there, it doesn't look in other folders to find it.

Comment: @hichris123 If I dont import my R file I'm getting error as `cannot resolve symbol R`wherever I use R. in my activity. Can you explain why we dont need to import it and how can I solve my problem?